# Update old data in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, insert-update

hi I have old data and I want to recover them .Lets say I have the following tables .

Table1:

| Company | FirstName |
| --- | --- |
| All | Beornræd |

Table2:

| CompanyNames |
| --- |
| X |
| Y |
| Z |

I want to map All to all values of the table of company such that I obtain the following result.

Table1: after update

| Company | FirstName |
| --- | --- |
| X | Beornræd |
| Y | Beornræd |
| Z | Beornræd |

I there a way to update them using a query and thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see that ALL has any significance - unless you also have something which is not ALL (some perhaps).

Answer (score 0):

Two simple steps (update (with a cross join) + delete) look the simplest to me - at least, with as many info and sample data you provided.

```
SQL> insert into table1 (company, firstname)
  2    select b.companynames, a.firstname
  3    from table1 a cross join table2 b;

3 rows created.

SQL> delete from table1 where company = 'All';

1 row deleted.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from table1;

COM FIRSTNAME
--- ---------
X   Beornrad
Y   Beornrad
Z   Beornrad

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `MERGE` as only a single statement such as

```sql
MERGE INTO t1
USING (SELECT * FROM t1
       UNION ALL
       SELECT t2.companynames, t1.firstname
         FROM t2, t1) tt
   ON (t1.company = tt.company)
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                      INSERT VALUES(tt.company, tt.firstname)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
                  UPDATE SET t1.firstname = ''
                  DELETE WHERE 1 = 1
```

newly(unmatched rows for `t1.company = tt.company`) generated rows  are **inserted**, and the matched ones are **deleted**, where ***update*** dml is nothing but an auxiliary representation for deletion

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=482bd6fcbac57d783dce325fbd35f756)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If there are values in table1 Company column other than 'All' then you need to mention `t1.Company='All'` in where clause.

```
Select t2.CompanyNames, t1.FirstName
from table1 t1 cross join table2 t2
where t1.Company='All';
```

Comment: well the suggestion is true, but what OP needs is not a select but a dml statement.